# Trying to execute C++ in iOS Xcode project gives me an error

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, libraries

I'm trying to integrate some libraries that I have via Homebrew in my iOS Xcode project. I have some C++ files that uses them. When I run the project in my simulator, it gives me this error:

```
building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for macOS, file '/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.2_3/lib/libavfilter.dylib' for architecture x86_64
```